# PHP date_default_timezone_set устанавливает не верное время

Tags: php, timezone

Прописал на сервере date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Kiev") в результате date('Y-m-d H:i') выводит 2020-11-05 09:03, корректное время 12:03.

На сервере стоит PHP Version 7.2.0

Что еще нужно дописать/изменить для получения правильного результата?

Comment: Посмотрите разницу во времени между установленным Вами и возвращаемым сервером и Вы поймете какую зону он Вам возвращает. Предполагаю, что это `UTC`. Отсюда вытекает простое предположение - `date_default_timezone_set` не срабатывает. Сделайте проверку на значение возвращаемое этой функцией - мне кажется, что оно будет `false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот рабочее решение. Проверял на впс, где серверное время отличается от Киевского

```
$zone = new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Kiev');
$date = new \DateTime('now', $zone);

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

Comment: К сожалению у меня не сработало, вывело : 2020-11-05 10:28 , щас 2020-11-05 13:28

Comment: Можно выкрутится с помощью $date->modify , но хотелось бы норм. решение

Comment: ПОсмотрите в `php.ini` какая у вас зона

Comment: Сорян, видат на серваке сбито время. На другом сервере все норм.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте класс [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.datetime.php)

Пример: `new DateTimeZone("Europe/Amsterdam")`
А затем выводите текущее время из этого класса.

Comment: Написал так: 
`$now = new DateTime(); 
$tmstp=$now->getTimestamp();
$dt_now = new DateTime("@$tmstp",new DateTimeZone('Europe/Kiev'));
echo $dt_now->format('Y-m-d H:i');` - тут должен был получить дату время в соответствии с Europe/Kiev, а фактически -5ч. щас 13:07 а получаю 08:02

Comment: И как то изменение DateTimeZone никак не влияет на время. Тупо серверное  показывает и все.

Answer (score 0):

date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Cairo');

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: date_default_timezone_set() устанавливает часовой пояс по умолчанию, используемый всеми функциями даты/времени.

Comment: добавьте это, пожалуйста, в текст ответа, нажав [edit]